# Change the extjs theme using extjs-rails gem

Tags: extjs, rubygems, themes, extjs4.1

I'm using the extjs-rails gem http://rubygems.org/gems/extjs-rails in my rails app.

Now i'd like to use the Gray Theme that come with Extjs by default.

Some idea about how todo this?

Thanks.